# Use RoleManager to choose default launcher app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, launcher

Hello fellow developers.

I'm using this code to open a chooser for default launcher app:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    RoleManager roleManager = (RoleManager) getSystemService(Context.ROLE_SERVICE);
    if (roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_HOME)) {
        Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_HOME);
        ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // DEAL WITH ERROR
                }
            }
        );
        resultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
}
```

I was using **startActivityOnResult()** before, and it was working. But it's now deprecated. That's why I'm trying to use this new method, but it doesnt' work. Nothing happens. My app just crashes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your app is not meant exclusively for Android versions Q and newer, add "else".

Comment: Your resultLauncher should be registered before onCreate() in your activity.